# Laravel Blade Comment causes CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In a Laravel 4.2 app, I have this view file:

```
{{--
             <table>
               <thead>
                  <th>

                  </th>
                  <th>

                  </th>
                  <th>

                  </th>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>

                     </td>
                     <td>

                     </td>
                     <td>

                     </td>
                  </tr>

               </tbody>
            </table>
--}}
```

making this view causes a crash in the browser.

I don't know which part causes this, sometimes removing a single space resolves the problem.

There are similar questions but there was some blade commands within blade comments that caused it, here I have the same problem with pure HTML

EDIT:
Copy/pasting above code resolves the problem! please copy from this gist https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/ad0da06d727e9973ca9e/raw/8d38ad3b416e920a0f1b9b8a42385ae56f25dc20/gistfile1.txt

Answer (score 1):

This happened with laravel 5 as well. I fixed this by converting to php comment, ie replace

```
`{{--` with  `<?php /*`
```

and

```
`--}}` with  `*/ ?>`
```